# How to update dependent packages to resolve dependabot security allert

Tags: security

I forked my parachain from substrate-node-template (polkadot-v0.9.29).

There are several security alerts generated by github dependabot, I am sharing just one here for an example:

Security Alert (As generated by dependabot) :

**h2 vulnerable to denial of service**

Hyper is an HTTP library for Rust and h2 is an HTTP 2.0 client & server implementation for Rust. An issue was discovered in h2 v0.2.4 when processing header frames. It incorrectly processes the HTTP2 RST_STREAM frames by not always releasing the memory immediately upon receiving the reset frame, leading to stream stacking. As a result, the memory and CPU usage are high which can lead to a Denial of Service (DoS).

This issue affects users only when dealing with http2 connections.

**Solutions (As advised by dependabot):**

To updated dependend package "h2" to a version greater than or equal to: 0.3.17.

This is just one example, in most of the cases, it is advised to update the dependent package to some "patched" version. For this we need to change our cargo.lock. Now I have two questions here:

1. Is it a good practice to make changes manually to cargo.lock, since it is always advised not to change cargo.lock manually?
2. What is the best way to update these dependent packages without updating to a new version of polkadot?